# C:\fakepath\ Issue while downloading file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sample code with input type file and attached a file. I want download the same file when button click. when I try to download the file, I'm getting C:\fakepath\ Issue

Below is the code I tried

```
var filename = $(".attachment-form input[type='file'").val();
   //alert(filename + 'test');

   if (filename == "" || filename == null) {
            alert('Error');
        }else {
            var file =  document.getElementById('oFileUploaderInput-fu').files[0];
            var filename =  document.getElementById('oFileUploaderInput-fu').files[0].name;
            var blob = new Blob([file]);
            var url  = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            $("#oLink").attr({ 'download': filename, 'href': url});
            //alert(filename);
           filename = "";
        }
```

Please advice how to resole the fake path Issue.

Regards

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! please take short time to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and add all relevant things to your question/post

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. There have been [many questions and answers written about "C:\fakepath"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fakepath). Can you please tell us what about those existing questions and answers did not answer your current question?

Comment: FYI, form field value is not going to be null

Answer (score 1):

Reading the documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file), I see that `<input type="file" />` has a JavaScript `files` property which is a [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList), a list of [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) objects which inherits from [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob).

So you may just have to do:

```
var file = document.getElementById('oFileUploaderInput-fu').files[0];
var filename = file.name;
var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
$("#oLink").attr({ 'download': filename, 'href': url });
```

Tested, it works for me.